# Number of bipartite graphs given two sets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I'm currently studying for an exam related to graphs, reason why I have been asking several question of this topic. In this case, I am confused about the definition of **bipartite graph**, at least up to a certain point.

I am asked to find how many bipartite graphs are there so that the two sets of vertices are $V = \{v_1\dots v_n\}, W = \{w_1\dots w_m\}$. The question doesn't seem difficult, but I was wondering if this reasoning looks sound:

Supposing that $n > m$ (if it weren't like that, I would modify the proceeding by changing the letter), for each $v_i \in V$, one chooses from $m$ vertices of the set $W$, and therefore there are $m^n$ options. However, there remains a question: is it valid that any vertex of the set $W$ isn't connected to no vertex of set $V$? Besides, I haven't taken into account that it could be a vertex or more of the set $V$ those disconnected. If this isn't valid, then I would say the answer is $m! S(n,m)$, being $S(n,m)$ the Stirling number of the second kind. To resume: how to calculate how many bipartite graphs are there?

Comment: You seem to be thinking about a function rather than a graph.  I would expect $2^{\text{something}}$ in your answer

Comment: Indeed, I always tend to think bipartite graphs as representation of functions of discrete variable

Comment: As a matter of convenient terminology, the two disjoint vertex sets $V,W$ would often be called the *parts* of a bipartite graph on those vertices.  A counting of graphs depends on whether you mean these as labelled or unlabelled, that is whether two isomorphic graphs are counted together provided the isomorphism is just a relabelling of the vertices.  I suspect you were ask to consider the graphs as labelled (since the notation for vertices allows this).

Comment: Labelled, of course

Comment: I also suspect that a vertex in one part or the other may be connected to zero or many vertices in the other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One more hint.

In a total of $mn$ edges can be drawn in a bipartite graph with parts of size $m$ and $n$. Each of these edges we either conduct or not.

Addition.
Hence we conclude that the number of labelled bipartite graphs is $2^{mn}$.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to conclude it. Do you mean separating in cases?

Comment: @DanielC. Well I have made an addendum to my reply. This is no longer a hint but a complete solution.

Comment: @DanielC.  If you want to think in terms of counting functions, consider the functions from $V$ to the power set of $W$.  That is, any vertex in $V$ may have edges to any subset of $W$.

Comment: Every edge will be of the form $v_i w_j$, so any vertex $v_i$ will have anywhere from 0 to $m$ neighbors. Thus the total number of edges is $0 \leq |E| \leq nm$. And because each of the $nm$ potential edges can either be present or be absent, the total number of graphs possible is, as others have said, $2^{nm}$.

Comment: What the sense do the parameters $m$ and $n$ have?

Comment: @VadimChernetsov Thank you for your question. These are the sizes of the parts of the bipartite graph.